# skb allocation failures in 2.6.32

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

We are running CentOS 6.3 (based on 2.6.32) and under high load we receive order 0 allocation failures when allocating skb. This problem is not inspected on CentOS 5.4 (based on 2.6.18).

This problem is very similar to https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14141.
The bug 14141 is closed by some patch (related to tty), that I don't sure is related to the problem.

Here is a very long discussion in lkml regarding the bug (see https://lkml.org/lkml/2009/10/2/86), which ends by some possible leads regarding `congestion_wait()` and more, but without patch.

I saw some proposals to inrcease `vm.min_free_kbytes`. IMHO it's not a solution, but rather workaround.

I suppose the problem was solved, but can't find when and how.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of high load do you have? What are exact error messages?